# xsl link to open popup window

Tags: xslt, hyperlink, popup

I have following XsL which opens the link in the same window. I would like add target _blank that will open a new window but not new window in a tab. Also resize it. I tried below but is not working.

```
<a href="{$modifiedUrl}" target="_blank"> view more </a>
```

Comment: Check this **[How to open popup dialog in ItemStyle.XSL?](https://debug.to/3002/how-to-open-popup-dialog-in-itemstyle-xsl)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put quotes around _blank:

```
<a href="{$modifiedUrl}" target="_blank">
```

Your current markup is not valid xml.

Comment: Sorry I meant the new window opens (forgot to add ") but i needed to be pop up window. Not just add a tab. and possibly smaller window size or resize the window.

Comment: Use a window.open if you'd like to specify the size: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp.  Register it in the onclick event of the link. ie href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open(...)"

Comment: I am bit lost. Are you saying I need to add a CEWP web part on the page. Then change <a href="{$modifiedUrl}" target="_blank"> to <a href=javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open"{$modifiedUrl}" target="_blank"> and pop up window in the center.

Comment: You'll need to specify the size parameters as well: window.open({$modifiedUrl},'NAME','height=400,width=200')